# What is the Time Complexity of creating set from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, set

I want to find time complexity of following code. I have an array of integer having duplicate values. I created set from array to remove duplicate entries and then initialize new array from that set using spread operator.

Code:

```
let list=[1,1,2,3,4,4]
let uniqueNumbers=[...new Set(list)]
console.log(uniqueNumbers)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 2 things being done here:

- `new Set(list)` iterates over every element of the `list` and puts it into a Set. This is `O(n)`
- `[...set]` iterates over every element of the Set and puts it into an array. This will also be `O(n)` in nearly all cases.

Both operations are `O(n)`, so overall, the computational complexity is `O(n)`.